# How to write a URLClassLoader in Java such that it can execute a block of code prior to loading certain classes?

Tags: java

```
public class MyClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {

    public MyClassLoader() throws Exception{
         super(new URL[]{new URL("file:///home/ubuntu/java/hello.jar")});
    }

    @Override
    public Class loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        if (name.equals("hello.example.org.Foo") || name.equals("hello.example.org.Bar")) 
        {
            System.out.println("Foo or Bar is loaded");
        }
        return super.loadClass(name);

    }
```

}

I just want to execute a block of code prior to loading certain classes and the above code doesn't quite work and I am not sure where the error is?

once I have all my classes in jar file I would run it as follows

```
java -Djava.system.class.loader=MyClassLoader -jar hello.jar
```

Comment: you should add code which shows how you use `MyClassLoader`

Comment: done! I just edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You should override [`findClass(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#findClass-java.lang.String-) instead of [loadClass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass-java.lang.String-).

Comment: Well I am not quite sure how that works. for example my java classes inside a jar file will use some standard Java classes but I would rather try to avoid taking care of loading those standard Java classes unless I have to..URLCLassLoader extends ClassLoader

Answer (score 0):

If you set the system class loader via `-Djava.system.class.loader=MyClassLoader` you need to provide a constructor with a classloader parameter:

```
public MyClassLoader(ClassLoader parent) throws Exception{
     super(new URL[]{new URL("file:///home/ubuntu/java/hello.jar")}, parent);
}
```

You should have seen a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException` if you run without such a constructor.

Comment: You are absolutely right! However when I do that the parent ClassLoader will load all the my java classes so I couldn't execute a block code prior to loading certain classes which is my ultimate goal as per the question. I am happy to provide more information if needed.